# Linear Programming: algorithm to check if ratios can be combined with n bottles to equal a given ratio

Tags: linear-programming

Say you have n bottles. each with a ratio of $(a_i: b_i: c_i)$.
($a_i/(a_i+b_i+c_i),\cdots$ swap out the numerator for $b_i$ and $c_i$ respectively).

Now you are given a ratio of $(a:b:c)$. Use Linear programming to find an efficient algorithm to this problem. If it's yes, you can output the parts of bottles that gave you the answer. (e.g. 2 parts from one bottle, 1 part from another bottles.)

So it's not clear how to do this. One of my first thoughts was to make a variable $z = \sum(\alpha_i*(a_i,b_i,c_i)) - (a,b,c)$. This, I'm thinking could be the objective function we minimize.

Not sure if this works. Or if it does, where to go from here. Also, I'm not sure if I can have the alphas in the thing I'm trying to minimize. What am I supposed to do with these alphas.

Not sure what it means by algorithm either. That is, even if I could set up the problem as a linear problem, not sure what the algorithm would be.

Comment: I have trouble understanding your problem formulation. Can you please clarify what your objective is, and what the a,b,c means?

Comment: Hint: first, show that you can solve the problem if you can find out whether the ratio $(a:b:c)$ is in the convex hull of the points $(a_i:b_i:c_i)$. This is a **feasibility** problem and not an **optimization** problem. If you know the terminology, this is Phase 1 and not Phase 2. The "algorithm" the homework problem is looking for is probably of the form: (i) do *x* to create a linear programming problem. (ii) solve the problem. (iii) do *y* to extract the solution of your problem from the solution of the LP.

Comment: @Peter Shor say more. Apparently, I don't understand the terminology. Don't you need to create an objective function to min/max in linear programming.

Comment: @adrianN a,b,c are given. You are given n bottles that have some concentrations (a_i,b_i,c_i). Now figure out if some linear combination can satisfy (a,b,c). I don't know that objective function is. That's part of the problem. It's not obvious what it should be.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what class this is for, and how much linear programming you are learning in it, so I don't really know what you need.

One way to do it: assuming $a_i + b_i + c_i = 1, \ \forall i$, use the linear program:

$$ \max x$$

such that

$$\eqalign{
\sum_i  a_i \lambda_i &= a,\\
\sum_i  b_i \lambda_i &= b,\\
\sum_i  c_i \lambda_i &= c, \\
\lambda _i -x &\geq 0 \quad \forall i.
}$$

If there is a solution with $x \geq 0$, then you're done. Why? If $x \geq 0$, then there is a set of positive $\lambda_i$ satisfying the first three equations above: $\sum_i a_i \lambda_i = a$. The $\lambda_i$ give you the proportions with which to mix the bottles.  If one of the $\lambda_i$ were less than $0$, then this would tell you to add a negative amount from that bottle, yielding an unphysical "solution". If there is no solution of the linear program with $x \geq 0$, then no combination will give the proportions $a:b:c$, as that would give a solution to the linear program with $x \geq 0$.

Comment: Okay. The first 3 constraints make sense. But why do the lambdas need to sum to one. And what is x? And lambda_i >= x? which lambda is this? And why does it need to be at least x? Gracias.

Comment: It should have read $\lambda_i \geq x$ for all $i$. And the $\lambda_i$ summing to $1$ is a superfluous constraint (it's implied by the others), so you can actually get rid of that one. Although I think it might be good to leave it in for pedagogical reasons.

Comment: if x>=0, then your're done. Does that mean you have found the solution to be feasible or infeasible?

Comment: is this an algorithm?

Comment: what does lambda_i >=x even mean? How do you evaluate that if you don't know what x is?

Comment: This is a linear program: $x$ is the variable that you are trying to maximize. The $\lambda_i$ are variables, and $a_i$, $b_i$, $c_i$, $a$, $b$, and $c$. are constant values that are part of the input to your problem. If this is homework, you really need to look at your materials and try to understand linear programming better.